# Hosts entry for a fileserver don't work, why?

Tags: windows, network-shares, hosts

I have several entries in my `hosts` file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) for some servers with MS SQL Server. Does this work for fileservers (a first quick tests failed, Why)?

Edit: Access should be possible in console with a `dir \\fileserver\share\*.*`.

Comment: Because there's something  wring with your hosts entries, or your "quick tests". If you show the details of those to us, we may be able to tell you *what* is wrong.

Comment: Give us more details, so we can help you. And are you sure the application that connects to the server uses the hostname and not the ip address?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/122668/how-to-define-an-alias-name-for-a-given-fileserver/122672#122672 which has already been answered

Comment: Also, please avoid adding signature or tag-lines to the bottom of your posts. Since this is a question&answer site and not a discussion forum they are unnecessary and frowned upon.

Comment: It depends if the Fileserver is a windows 2003 or a windwos 2008 - Server. If the latter is the target it works without the anoying domain.
Althought the Thread is closed i'm posting the solution here, if there is somebody who is interested. Hopefully helpfull.
The WHY is'nt explained yet...

Comment: I asked for a solution within the local hosts... I found a possibility in hosts: 192.168.1.2 domain.servername but now we have to use the real 'domainname' to access the share e.g.: dir \\domain.fileserver\share How to get rid of that domain prefix?