# How-To define an Alias-Name for a given Fileserver?

Tags: network-shares, file-sharing, smb

I'm building a testsystem and want to use the servernames like in the productive environment.
For tcp-traffic i made an entry in the hosts-file but that seems not to work for fileservers (smb).

How may i define an Alias-Name like (\Filer) for my fileserver  with IP:192.168.1.2  and Name \testshare in our test-domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable [strict name checking](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281308/en-us) on the server. If you have a DNS server on your test domain, you can add a CNAME instead of editing the host files.

Comment: I got a solution by try and error: a hosts entry like:
192.168.134.1.2 domain.servername
works. explorer soomthly opened the fileshare on \\domain\servername\share...
But i don't like this domain here at this point - how to get rid of that?